# Qt4 & Qt5: How to fix Segmentation Fault Caused By the Function viz::WCloud

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5, qt4, dji-sdk

in my program C ++ opencv, I use several processing (rectification, stereoBM ...) on jetson TX2

accctually I used the function of SKD-DJI unprojectPtCloud for unproject 3D point cloud, but segmentation fault is occurred

1. first, I just add this functions in the file of the `functions.cpp` by putting the dernier line in comment (without calling the function unprojet from the `main ()`)

```
void Disparity_filter::unprojectPtCloud(std::shared_ptr<Frame> framel)
{
  // due to rectification, the image boarder are blank
  // we cut them out
  const int border_size = num_disp_;
  const int trunc_img_width_end = HEIGHT - border_size;
  const int trunc_img_height_end = WIDTH - border_size;

    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> mat_vec3_pt_ = cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f>(HEIGHT, WIDTH, cv::Vec3f(0, 0, 0));
    cv::Mat  color_mat_(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC1, &color_buffer_[0])  ;
  for(int v = border_size; v < trunc_img_height_end; ++v)
  {
    for(int u = border_size; u < trunc_img_width_end; ++u)
    {
      cv::Vec3f &point = mat_vec3_pt_.at<cv::Vec3f>(v, u);

#ifdef USE_OPEN_CV_CONTRIB
      float disparity = (float)(framel->raw_disparity_map_.at<short int>(v, u)*0.0625);
#else
      float disparity = (float)(framel->raw_disparity_map_.at<short int>(v, u)*0.0625);
#endif

      // do not consider pts that are farther than 8.6m, i.e. disparity < 6
      if(disparity >= 6)
      {
        point[2] = baseline_x_fx_/disparity;
        point[0] = (u-principal_x_)*point[2]/fx_;
        point[1] = (v-principal_y_)*point[2]/fy_;
      }
      color_buffer_[v*WIDTH+u] = framel->cpu_crop_left.at<uint8_t>(v, u);
    }
  }

  color_mat_ = cv::Mat(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC1, &color_buffer_[0]).clone();

    //cv::viz::WCloud pt_cloud_ = cv::viz::WCloud(mat_vec3_pt_, color_mat_); // this line commented in 1. and remouved the // in 2. 
}
```

I compile it, and I run it and it works

I `ldd` the executable and I found these library :

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~version_04 /build$ ldd stereo_vision 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x0000007fa62ab000)
    libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa60bd000)
    libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa59f3000)
    libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa57d5000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x0000007fa572b000)
    libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa525b000)
    libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa511d000)
    libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa50c3000)
    libopencv_videoio.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa507f000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa4c8d000)
    libopencv_core.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa47b5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007fa4626000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007fa4605000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007fa45d8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007fa4491000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x000000555f7c8000)
    libcudart.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 (0x0000007fa442c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007fa437e000)
    libnppc.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppc.so.9.0 (0x0000007fa4304000)
    libnppig.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppig.so.9.0 (0x0000007fa265f000)
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 (0x0000007fa24c9000)
    libtbb.so => /usr/local/lib/libtbb.so (0x0000007fa2485000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000007fa2457000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000007fa2440000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x0000007fa2413000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x0000007fa2378000)
    libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.4 (0x0000007f9ee89000)
    libnppial.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppial.so.9.0 (0x0000007f9e406000)
    libnppicc.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppicc.so.9.0 (0x0000007f9dfbc000)
    libnppidei.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppidei.so.9.0 (0x0000007f9d7f4000)
    libnppist.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppist.so.9.0 (0x0000007f9c804000)
    libnpps.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnpps.so.9.0 (0x0000007f9be63000)
    libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4 (0x0000007f9a528000)
    libopencv_flann.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.4 (0x0000007f9a4c5000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x0000007f9a497000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libGL.so.1 (0x0000007f9a397000)
    libQt5Test.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x0000007f9a351000)
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x0000007f9a2ee000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x0000007f99d28000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x0000007f998ad000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x0000007f993e7000)
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f992c7000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x0000007f9926a000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x0000007f99163000)
    libgstapp-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f99147000)
    libgstriff-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstriff-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f99129000)
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f990e7000)
    libv4l1.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0 (0x0000007f990d1000)
    libv4l2.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0 (0x0000007f990b3000)
    libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x0000007f980e5000)
    libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x0000007f97f06000)
    libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 (0x0000007f97e93000)
    libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3 (0x0000007f97e22000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000007f97e0f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000007f97de7000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x0000007f97da1000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x0000007f97d71000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x0000007f97cf9000)
    libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x0000007f97c9c000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x0000007f97c2a000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x0000007f97c09000)
    libnppif.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppif.so.9.0 (0x0000007f940ad000)
    libnppim.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppim.so.9.0 (0x0000007f93b76000)
    libnppitc.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libnppitc.so.9.0 (0x0000007f9387e000)
    libcublas.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so.9.0 (0x0000007f91a4d000)
    libcufft.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcufft.so.9.0 (0x0000007f8a973000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libGLX.so.0 (0x0000007f8a930000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x0000007f8a804000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x0000007f8a6db000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x0000007f8a678000)
    libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x0000007f8a40a000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x0000007f8a26c000)
    libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x0000007f8a206000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x0000007f8a1f2000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x0000007f8a1d9000)
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f8a172000)
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f8a10c000)
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f8a0c5000)
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f8a043000)
    libv4lconvert.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert.so.0 (0x0000007f89fbd000)
    libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 (0x0000007f89f99000)
    libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x0000007f89f6f000)
    libzvbi.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x0000007f89ee0000)
    libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x0000007f89df1000)
    libx265.so.79 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.79 (0x0000007f89be8000)
    libx264.so.148 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.148 (0x0000007f89a80000)
    libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 (0x0000007f89a24000)
    libwavpack.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwavpack.so.1 (0x0000007f899f0000)
    libvpx.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3 (0x0000007f89883000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x0000007f897d4000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x0000007f8979d000)
    libtwolame.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtwolame.so.0 (0x0000007f8976d000)
    libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x0000007f8972b000)
    libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x0000007f89706000)
    libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x0000007f896e1000)
    libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x0000007f896c9000)
    libshine.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x0000007f896ac000)
    libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 (0x0000007f895d6000)
    libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x0000007f89589000)
    libopenjpeg.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.5 (0x0000007f89559000)
    libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x0000007f894e0000)
    libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x0000007f894c6000)
    libssh-gcrypt.so.4 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 (0x0000007f89478000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x0000007f8944e000)
    libmodplug.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libmodplug.so.1 (0x0000007f892bc000)
    libgme.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x0000007f89264000)
    libbluray.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.1 (0x0000007f89215000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x0000007f890ef000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x0000007f890cf000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x0000007f890b1000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x0000007f89091000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x0000007f89065000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x0000007f88fc8000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x0000007f88f9b000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x0000007f876d3000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x0000007f87658000)
    libsoxr.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x0000007f875f4000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x0000007f875d6000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x0000007f875be000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000007f8756f000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x0000007f8752e000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x0000007f874ee000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x0000007f87470000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x0000007f872db000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x0000007f8728e000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x0000007f87223000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x0000007f871e0000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x0000007f871bf000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x0000007f871ab000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x0000007f87196000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000007f870cd000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000007f87091000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000007f8707d000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000007f87063000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x0000007f8702e000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000007f8701a000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000007f86ff4000)
```

and that of Qt library are:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/version_04/build$ ldd stereo_vision | grep libQ
    libQt5Test.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x0000007f855c6000)
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x0000007f85563000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x0000007f84f9d000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x0000007f84b22000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x0000007f8465c000)
```

2. I removed the comment and I recompile the program and He did not report errors and no warnings!

When I run the executable. It stops with segmentation fault (without show the debug message I put in the `main()`

I `gdb` the executable, it showed me an error regarding `libQtGui.so.4`, so I remove `libqt4` and I reinstall it.

I have to retry and now it shows me a segmentation fault here:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~version_04 /build$ gdb stereo_vision 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "aarch64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from stereo_vision...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/nvidia/stage/version_04_04_dji /build/stereo_vision 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007f99ca57b0 in QBasicAtomicInt::ref (this=<optimized out>)
    at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_aarch64.h:116
116    ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_aarch64.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) Quit
```

When loading the linked library, I found that the ex is linked with Qt4 and Qt5:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/version_04 /build$ ldd stereo_vision |grep libQt
    libQt5Test.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x0000007f75345000)
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x0000007f752e3000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x0000007f74d1c000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x0000007f748a1000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x0000007f743dc000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x0000007f64c37000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x0000007f6493a000)
```

I can't solve the problem ..

Is it normal the add of this line of code, the program is will be linked with Qt4 and Qt5 without calling the function unproject from the `main()`?

How can I use cv::viz::WCloud ?

Comment: First, you have a lot of libraries! It is possible for the libraries you are using to use `dlopen()` or other functions to load separate libraries from what `ldd` shows. Qt itself does this with its platform folders. Second, segfaults are most often associated with a pointer overflow elsewhere in the program that corrupts the program but doesn't show up until later. Try running valgrind on it and see if it finds any out-of-bounds memory access.